# How to achieve smooth motion animation using devicemotion rotationRate data

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the `rotationRate` data from the `devicemotion` eventListener to tilt a `three.js` scene. The scene does tilt in the correct angle using that data, however it results in a choppy-like motion effect. Is there a way I can smooth out the motion effect?

I am currently mapping the `event.beta` and `event.gamma` data to the appropriate angles for the `three.js` camera tilt, however since the rotation-data is used directly for the angle update, the result is not quite smooth. I have tried multiplying the angle to a smaller number, but that doesn't quite smooth out the motion.

```
function handleDeviceMotion(event) {
    rotateX = Math.clip(parseInt((event.rotationRate.beta*10).toFixed(0)), -rotationContain, rotationContain);
    rotateY = Math.clip(parseInt((event.rotationRate.alpha*10).toFixed(0)), -rotationContain, rotationContain);
    rotateXMapped = rotateX.map(-rotationContain, rotationContain, -paneAngleContain, paneAngleContain);
    rotateYMapped = rotateY.map(-rotationContain, rotationContain, -paneAngleContain, paneAngleContain);
    rotateXMapped += 0.3;
    rotateYMapped += 0.3;
}
```

The `rotateXMap` and `rotateYMap` are then used later in the `orbitControls.js` library provided by `three.js`. Is there a way to potentially add a delay to the movement from the current angle to the updated one? Math isn't my strong suit and have been trying to work this out for some time now.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was just missing some [lerp interpolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) to smooth out the motion of the tilt data. Where that formula takes the future point, current point, and averages them. Resulting in a smooth animation.

I found a great [lerp demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/ma77os/pen/KGIEh).

Here's my updated code in action:

```
function handleDeviceMotion(event) {
    // contain rotationRate data, then map it to appropriate scene tilt angles, add lerp to smooth effect
    rotateX = Math.clip(parseInt((event.rotationRate.beta*10).toFixed(0)), -rotationContain, rotationContain);
    rotateY = Math.clip(parseInt((event.rotationRate.alpha*10).toFixed(0)), -rotationContain, rotationContain);
    rotateXMapped = rotateX.map(-rotationContain, rotationContain, -paneAngleContain, paneAngleContain);
    rotateYMapped = rotateY.map(-rotationContain, rotationContain, -paneAngleContain, paneAngleContain);
    rotateXLerp = lerp(rotateXLerp, rotateXMapped, 0.15); // 0.1 = default
    rotateYLerp = lerp(rotateYLerp, rotateYMapped, 0.15); // 0.1 = default
}

function lerp(start, end, amt) {
    return (1-amt)*start+amt*end;
}
```

I hope this helps anyone in the future!

Comment: Without knowing what `Math.clip` does, what `rotateX.map()` does, what are the values of `paneAngleContain` and `rotationContain` etc etc, you answer might be pretty hard for someone coming to it to reason about how this one actually helped in resolving the problem. So far it's only helpful to you, I presume.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into jittery animation because you're using the [devicemotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/devicemotion) event (which is mainly used to capture changes in acceleration) instead of the [deviceorientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/deviceorientation) event (which is mainly used to capture changes in orientation). `deviceorientation` is the recommended method that Three.js uses for its DeviceOrientation controls, which you can see in action here: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=dev#misc_controls_deviceorientation

Just to be safe, have you tried running your scene with a very simple setup? This could help rule out the possibility that you're getting low framerate from other performance bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do have to use `devicemotion` instead of `deviceorientation`, due to the tilt constraints on the project. Having done more research, I need to implement some form of [lerp interpolation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) to add some form of animation delay/ averaging to create a smooth animation. Math is hard :P

Comment: Ah, if you need to constrain angles, you might run into gimbal lock when crossing axes. Sometimes isolating `.alpha & .beta` can yield to jumps from + to - unexpectedly. I made a tool that isolates this into `yaw, pitch, roll` with minimal gimbal lock, if you think it'll be of help: https://github.com/marquizzo/three-gimbal (I realize this is an off-site resource, but it might be of help to your case.)

Comment: Yes! I've run into gimbal lock on so many occasions! I will definitely check out your solution. Thank you :)